# Update table with data from secondary table by foreignkey

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: `tableA` and `tableB`. I want to remove `tableB` hence it is redundant, so i need to copy the column values from `tableB` to `tableA`.

tableA:

```
|    id    |    name    |    tableA_id    |
```

tableB

```
|    id    |    tableC_id    |    tableD_id    |
```

`tableA` has been altered so it has the additional columns as `tableA`:

```
|    id    |    name    |    tableA_id    |    tableC_id    |    tableD_id    |
```

So basically i want to copy the columns `tableB.tableC_id` and `tableB.tableD_id` into `tableA.tableC_id` and `tableA.tableD_id`.

How can i pull this off in a SQL update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You update with an UPDATE. ;-)

```
UPDATE tableA inner join tableB on tableA.id = tableB.id set tableA.tableC_id = tableB.tableC_id, tableA.tableD_id = tableB.tableD_id;
```